# Removing dotted assist lines?

Tags: objects, 3d-view, parent

When I open the file directly from my desktop, these assist lines don't seem to show. But when I Append it, these random dotted lines appear that seem to point to its parented object. Is there any way to hide these lines, because they can start to get really distracting when animating.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can hide that in display tab by deselecting Relationship Lines.

Press N while in 3D-view, then uncheck the option in "Display":

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot showing where for people?

Answer (score 5):

For Blender 2.8x

Click on the Overlays drop down menu (usually found near the top right corner of the 3D Viewport) and uncheck the box next to Relationship Lines.

[image]