# Visual aid to show IK Rotation Limitations

Tags: rigging

I'm working with rigging right now and would like to know if there is any visual aid in blender 2.7x to show me the limitations of a bone rotation in a chain?

Such as in this picture of 2.6 documentation:

[image]

I can't find any button or shortcut to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27143/removing-dotted-assist-lines-problem-only-occurs-when-appending

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two years and no answer, damn, I've been trying to find the answer to this for a while now and just decided to click on everything i could find and eventually found the answer.

In the properties panel, hot key is N, under the display sub heading, tick "Relationship Lines" and those visual aids should appear yet again.

Hope this helps anyone still looking for the answer.

Comment: Damn, I also forgot about this question. Never found a solution until now. Thank you a lot.